# atmega embedded C programming

Tags: c, embedded, atmega

I am trying to learn embedded C programming for atmega. I am stuck with this error called

> avr-gcc.exe(0,0): CreateProcess: No such file or directory

I have written a simple C code of about 10 lines.

```
/*
 * RAJESH_AVRC_PROG.c
 *
 * Created: 6/10/2017 10:33:39 PM
 *  Author: AMMU_AMMA
 */ 

#define F_CPU 2000000L
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avt/delay.>
int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    PORTB = 0xFF;

    while(1)
    {
        PORTB = 0xFF;
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTB=0x00;
        _delay_ms(1000);
        //TODO:: Please write your application code 
    }
}
```

Comment: It can't find your `avr-gcc.exe` compiler. totally unrelated to your code.

Comment: `avt/delay.` is a decidedly odd name for a file.

Comment: Lots to improve here as mentioned in the other comments.  I'm also curious how you arrived at your value for F_CPU.  That's not typical at all for first attempts.  Also it's `delay.h` and you need to find out where it really is on your system.  And of course find the compiler.  ;)

Comment: Downvoted for begging. It will probably be genuinely surprising to you that we get a few hundred posts a day pleading for assistance, and it really is counterproductive. People here are volunteers, and they do not need to see any attempts to get them to take on more work than they would normally have time for.

Comment: The problem is with how you set up your build environment.  From the looks of it, you're probably using GNU Make in Windows.  Make sure avr-gcc.exe is on your PATH environment variable.  If you need more help than that, you'll need to provide the details of how you set up your environment.

Comment: [This is for you](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avr-gcc-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a quick start, I suggest you use Linux (in a VM or on a separate PC). On Debian/Ubuntu, you can install the required tools on a terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get install avrdude gcc-avr
```

You can then use this to compile your files (for atmega32):

```
avr-gcc -Os -mmcu=atmega32 RAJESH_AVRC_PROG.c -o RAJESH_AVRC_PROG.elf && avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .text -j .data RAJESH_AVRC_PROG.elf  RAJESH_AVRC_PROG.hex
```

You can load the resulting hex file onto your AVR.

Comment: A Linux VM is an option, but a simpler one is that installing the arduino IDE  necessarily dumps a working avr-gcc somewhere - you only have to figure out where, and then you can readily use it for non-Arduino avr projects.